# manage packages of the system profile in NixOS

Tags: package-management, nixos, nix

In NixOS how can I manage the system installed packages?

If I run `nix-env -q` from root I get the packages installed by root (and available to all the users), but many are missing like `ssh`, the whole `kde`, the kernel and so on.

Also, how is this "system-profile" handled? Is it upgraded when I upgrade with `nix-env -u '*'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for system packages on nixos it is probably best to keep then in configuration.nix file (`environment.systemPackages`)

Comment: _Also, how is this "system-profile" handled?_ It's part of the system evaluation, so it's only switched by `nixos-rebuild`; e.g. all versions are consistent in the system.

Comment: for every change you do in your ``configuration.nix`` you need to trigger ``nixos-rebuild``. The same is true when you add/remove packages from ``environment.systemPackages`` list.